# Custom Control Draw Out of memory exception?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, graphics

I am learning how to draw custom controls and have put some code together but get a "Out of memory" exception while resizing the control. Although I dispose of my brushes and pencils after each draw, I still get this exception. Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong? I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D


Public Class Draw_Sub

Inherits Windows.Forms.Panel

Public Sub New()

    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Me.Width = 30
    Me.Height = 500

End Sub

Private Sub Draw_Sub_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Cntrls_Draw(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height, 3, e)
    Cntrls_Draw(0, 100, Me.Width, Me.Width, 3, e)

End Sub

Public Sub Cntrls_Draw(ByVal X_pos As Integer,
                       ByVal Y_pos As Integer,
                       ByVal Wdth As Integer,
                       ByVal Hght As Integer,
                       ByVal Bev_Hght As Integer,
                       ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)

    Dim Width_bev = Bev_Hght * 2 / Wdth
    Dim Width_Scale = 1 - Width_bev
    Dim Height_bev = Bev_Hght * 2 / Hght
    Dim Height_Scale = 1 - Height_bev

    Dim Draw_pnts As Point() = {New Point(X_pos, Y_pos),
                                New Point(Wdth, Y_pos),
                                New Point(Wdth, Hght),
                                New Point(X_pos, Hght)}

    Dim pthGrBrush As New PathGradientBrush(Draw_pnts)

    Dim colors As Color() = {Color.FromArgb(50, 49, 65, 81),
                             Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)}

    Dim relativePositions As Single() = {0.0F, 1.0F}
    pthGrBrush.FocusScales = New PointF(Width_Scale, Height_Scale)

    Dim colorBlend As New ColorBlend()
    colorBlend.Colors = colors
    colorBlend.Positions = relativePositions
    pthGrBrush.InterpolationColors = colorBlend

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pthGrBrush, 0, 0, Wdth, Hght)
    pthGrBrush.Dispose()

    'AO line rectangle to give a sharper look at the bottom sides
    Dim Rect As New Rectangle(Bev_Hght, Bev_Hght, Wdth - (Bev_Hght * 2), Hght - (Bev_Hght * 2))
    Dim My_Pen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(25, 0, 0, 0), 3)

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(My_Pen, Rect)
    My_Pen.Dispose()

End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: On which line does the exception happen?

Comment: It says line 19 and 40 . Maybe I am just doff from trying to figure it out for hours but I really don't see the problem

Comment: It happens with my second "pathGradientBrush" draw.

Comment: Is the problem happening in the Designer or at run-time? I tried to re-create the problem with the small corrections needed by using [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) (VS2015, Windows 10) and I didn't get any exceptions.

Comment: Its happening in the designer. I only need to resize my control in the designer.

Comment: OK, use Option Strict On (see the link in my previous comment for its documentation) and see if it still goes wrong when you have corrected the couple of problems it will point out for you.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Already reading the documentation from the link and it looks like it is the Double to Single conversion that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew Morton it seems that my problem was Double to Single conversion.
After changing this piece:

```
    Dim Width_bev = Bev_Hght * 2 / Wdth
    Dim Width_Scale = 1 - Width_bev
    Dim Height_bev = Bev_Hght * 2 / Hght
    Dim Height_Scale = 1 - Height_bev
```

To this:

```
    Dim Width_bev = CSng(Bev_Hght * 2 / Wdth)
    Dim Width_Scale = 1 - Width_bev
    Dim Height_bev = CSng(Bev_Hght * 2 / Hght)
    Dim Height_Scale = 1 - Height_bev
```

seems to have resolved the issue.